# Set cell data validation in macro (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to update a current macro enable excel document. Currently clicking a button creates a new row, I need two of these cells to have data validation enabled automatically is that even possible? Or if not possible could it draw the data validation from the cell below?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a copy of the current macro code available for us to look at?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions – Bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: A quick way to do it would be to copy the cell with data validation and then use PasteSpecial to paste the validation (`rng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValidation`).

Answer (score 0):

After you have inserted the row, use the below code to apply validation to a cell. You have to change the cell reference based on your needs (2 cells),

```
'update the correct cell reference after inserting a new row
'rownum will be the newly inserted row number
Cells(rownum, 1).Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=$B$1:$B$6"
```

Where `$B$1:$B$6` is the data validation selection range.